# why doesn't GCC place a statically-initialized C++ class object into .data

Tags: c++, gcc, static, initializer

here are two similar declarations of an object type in C++:

```
struct Obj {
    int x;
};

struct ObjC {
    int x;
    ObjC(int x) : x(x) {};
};

Obj obj1 = {100}
ObjC obj2(200);
```

using a recent version of gcc (`riscv64-unknown-elf-toolchain-10.2.0-2020.12.8`) i find that the variable `obj1` is correctly placed in the `.data` section....  the variable `obj2`, however, is placed in the `.bss` section where it is *not* initialized....

i know there are provisions in GCC to run constructors at startup; but in this case, the initial state of `obj2` is known at compile time....

FWIW, my IAR compiler has no problem with this code....

is there some sort of "hint" i need to provide to GCC????

Comment: Runtime constructor can only get constructed at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not marking the constuctor with `constexpr` seems to prevent optimizations here. The following type seems to get initialized properly, [see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%0Astruct+Obj+%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+ObjC+%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A++++ObjC(int+x)+:+x(x)+%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+ObjC2+%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A++++constexpr+ObjC2(int+x)+:+x(x)+%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AObj+obj1+%3D+%7B100%7D%3B%0AObjC+obj2(200)%3B%0AObjC2+obj3(300)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
struct ObjC2 {
    int x;
    constexpr ObjC2(int x)
        : x(x)
    {
    }
};

ObjC2 obj3(300);
```

Comment: constexpr is only a hint to evaluate at compile time, a promise that it can be. It doesn't need to be evaluated at compile time. `obj3` should be `constinit`.

Comment: `constinit` is a more recent C++ addition than `constexpr` -- and i tend to use the "oldest" version of the standard that work's for me....   FWIW, gcc does handle this situation as expected with just `constexpr`....

Answer (score 3):

If you want to increase the chance something gets evaluated at compile time and make the promise to the compiler that the code can be evaluated at compile time then add the `constexpr` keyword:

```
struct Obj {
    int x;
};

struct ObjC {
    int x;
    constexpr ObjC(int x) : x(x) {};
};
```

But that does not force the compiler to evaluate at compile time. For that mark the variables with `constinit`:

```
constinit Obj obj1 = {100}
constinit ObjC obj2(200);
```

Note: `constinit` does not make the variable `const`.

Comment: Of course nothing _really_ forces the compiler to do anything at compile-time, but even without `constinit`, the variable still has constant initialization, which means the compiler must make sure that it is initialized before any potential dynamic initialization uses it. Since that could happen in any translation unit, I don't think compilers really have a choice but to initialize at compile-time anyway. `constinit` just makes it an error if the initialization is not constant initialization.

Comment: @user17732522 The `constinit` actually forces the compiler to initialize at compile time or fail. The problem without `constinit` is that constant initialization comes with a lot of conditions: *Static or thread-local object of class type that is initialized by a constructor call, if the constructor is constexpr and all constructor arguments (including implicit conversions) are constant expressions, and if the initializers in the constructor's initializer list and the brace-or-equal initializers of the class members only contain constant expressions.* The `constinit` ensures those are met.